# React Native - Unable to pass CheckBox value to another screen

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native, checkbox

I'm here to ask what's your idea to properly pass a **CheckBox** value to other screen?

Example, if a user checks a CheckBox then proceed to the **Next Screen** the value of the **CheckBox** should be displayed in that screen.

But in my code, my console.log gives an output of false(I don't understand why) and once I get to the next screen the state doesn't really pass because it's display is blank.

Here's my code

```
export default class tables extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        ...
        check: {},
        tbl_Merge: []
    }
}

proceed_TO_Category = () => {
    this.props.navigation.navigate('Category', {
        userName    : this.state.userName,
        DineIn      : this.state.DineIn,
        tbl         : this.state.tbl,
        tbl_2nd     : this.state.tbl_2nd,
        tbl_Merge   : this.state.tbl_Merge
    });
    console.log("CHECK ======> "+ this.state.tbl_Merge);
}

checkBox_Test = (table_NO) => {
    const tbl_Merge = this.state.tbl_Merge;
    const checkCopy = {...this.state.check}
    if (checkCopy[table_NO]) {
        checkCopy[table_NO] = false;
    } else {
        checkCopy[table_NO] = true;
    }
    this.setState({ check: checkCopy });
    this.setState({ tbl_Merge: table_NO == this.state.tbl_Merge });
}

render() {
    return(
         <View>
              ....
              <Flatlist
                    ....
                    <CheckBox
                       value = { this.state.check[item.tbl_id] }
                       onChange = {() => this.checkBox_Test(item.tbl_id) }
                    />
                    ....
              />
              ....
                    <View>
                        <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress = {() => this.proceed_TO_Category()}>
                            <Text>Categories</Text>
                        </TouchableOpacity>
                    </View>
         <View/>
    )
}
}
```

Screen shot of Console.log in my **proceed_TO_Category.**
[image: Console.log]

Comment: What is your Flatlist data? Specially tbl_id.

Comment: my checkbox is placed inside my flatlist, and I use fetch to display some item in my flatlist also -- I called them "tbl_id". So, each item have their own checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
checkBox_Test = (table_NO) => {
    const tbl_Merge = this.state.tbl_Merge;
    const checkCopy = {...this.state.check}
    if (checkCopy[table_NO]) {
        checkCopy[table_NO] = false;
    } else {
        checkCopy[table_NO] = true;
    }
    this.setState({ check: checkCopy, tbl_Merge: table_NO == this.state.tbl_Merge }); // 1. Edit
}
```

1. Edit: We should not use setState consecutively. Because setState is async func. If you want to call a function after setState process with the help of callback function,`setState(update, callback);`
2. you defined tbl_Merge as an array, but while you set it to state, you set it as a boolean.